# Create plugin to edit category form

Tags: plugin, category

i'm trying to edit joomla's category form with a plugin following this guide
https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin

xml file

```
<extension version="3.1" type="plugin" group="category">
    <name>plg_img_categories</name>     
    <files>
        <filename plugin="categories">categoryimg.php</filename>
        <folder>forms</folder>
    </files>

</extension>
```

php file

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

class plgContentCategoryCategories extends JPlugin {
    function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data) {
        echo "Pippo!";
        var_dump($form->getName());
    }
 }
?>
```

I was expected to see var_dump "$form->getName()" or "Pippo!" inside the administrator category form, however it doesn't.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no plugin group like `category`, you should use `content` in this case.

Joomla! relies strongly on naming conventions:

- Class name should be `plg[GROUP_NAME][PLUGIN_ATTR_VALUE]`, resulting in `plgContentCategoryImg`
- Plugin name in XML should be `plg_[GROUP_NAME]_[PLUGIN_ATTR_VALUE]`, resulting in `plg_content_categoryimg`.
- Plugin directory name must be `[PLUGIN_ATTR_VALUE]`, resulting in `categoryimg`

So, your files would look like this:

**categoryimg.php**

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

class plgContentCategoryImg extends JPlugin {
    function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data) {
        echo "Pippo!";
        var_dump($form->getName());
    }
 }
?>
```

**categoryimg.xml**

```
<extension version="3.1" type="plugin" group="content">
    <name>plg_content_categoryimg</name>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="categoryimg">categoryimg.php</filename>
    </files>
</extension>
```

And don't forget, directory name must be `categoryimg`.

Result as I tested it:

[image]

Comment: You are my HERO! 
Thanks mate!